# Tomcat client-cert authentication with DN with special characters

Tags: tomcat, authentication, ssl, special-characters, client-certificates

I am trying to set client authentication on tomcat server when client certificate DN is checked against database, but i have one issue.

1. 2way authentication is set, client certificate is always needed.
2. CLIENT-CERT authentication is set for web application.
3. DN from certificate is checked against oracle DB.

There is problem with part of our clients. When client has NO special character in his name (and in his certificate), there is no problem and client is allowed to access web application.
In case when client has special chars in his name (`ěščřžýáíé`), tomcat is not matching DN with record in database. I set loging for authentication and there is one example:

DN in database (`EMAIL=tomas.kanak@xxx.cz`, `CN=Tomáš Kaňak`, ...)
DN, which is compared with one in DB (i get this from tomcat logs) (`EMAIL=tomas.kanak@xxx.cz`, `CN=TomÃ¡Å¡ KnÅ<88>ak`, ...)

I've tried to put DN from logs to database, but no luck.

Is there any way I can authenticate certificates of clients with special characters?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure that the public cert is OK? It seems like that some point of your chain does not translate bytes to chars correctly.

Comment: My certificates are made in openssl. Maybe that's the problem. I created CA certificate and then signed server and client certificates. Can I force openssl to use different codepage to solve my problem? What do you think?

Comment: I did not say that OpenSSL is the problem. I simply mean that there is some problem in your chain. If you are able to dump the bytes from the public cert, you'll see whether they are encoded correctly.

Comment: I've created new CA/server/client certs and it looks like everything is OK now. I realy do not understand why and how its possible. Thank you.